# Mapping Mysql Result to Custom Json Format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to mapping the mysql result into json encode, but the result is not as i want.

Results From the Mysql Query

[image: Mysql Result]

**`print_r($data)`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => Januari
            [Total] => 1
            [Langsung] => 0
            [Delivery] => 1
            [Dropship] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => Februari
            [Total] => 24
            [Langsung] => 19
            [Delivery] => 4
            [Dropship] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => Maret
            [Total] => 0
            [Langsung] => 0
            [Delivery] => 0
            [Dropship] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => April
            [Total] => 0
            [Langsung] => 0
            [Delivery] => 0
            [Dropship] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => Mei
            [Total] => 0
            [Langsung] => 0
            [Delivery] => 0
            [Dropship] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => Juni
            [Total] => 0
            [Langsung] => 0
            [Delivery] => 0
            [Dropship] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => Juli
            [Total] => 0
            [Langsung] => 0
            [Delivery] => 0
            [Dropship] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => Agustus
            [Total] => 0
            [Langsung] => 0
            [Delivery] => 0
            [Dropship] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => September
            [Total] => 0
            [Langsung] => 0
            [Delivery] => 0
            [Dropship] => 0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => Oktober
            [Total] => 0
            [Langsung] => 0
            [Delivery] => 0
            [Dropship] => 0
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => November
            [Total] => 0
            [Langsung] => 0
            [Delivery] => 0
            [Dropship] => 0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [Bulan] => Desember
            [Total] => 0
            [Langsung] => 0
            [Delivery] => 0
            [Dropship] => 0
        )

)
```

If I use **`echo json_encode($data);`**
The Result like This:

```
[
  {
    "Bulan": "Januari",
    "Total": "1",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "1",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Februari",
    "Total": "24",
    "Langsung": "19",
    "Delivery": "4",
    "Dropship": "1"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Maret",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "April",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Mei",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Juni",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Juli",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Agustus",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "September",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Oktober",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "November",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Desember",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  }
]
```

**My Expected** Like This:

```
{
        "Bulan"     : ["Januari", "Februari", "Maret", "April","Mei","Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember"],
        "Total"     : [1,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "Langsung"  : [0,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "Delivery"  : [1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        "Dropship"  : [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
      }
```

Is possible to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u explain to me, how to do that?

Comment: Do your `while` and add values to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways.. without testing anything i think it should look something like this

```
$output=array();
foreach($data as $entry)
foreach($entry as $k=>$v)
{
if(!is_array($output[$k]))
$output[$k]=array();
$output[$k][]=$v;
}

print_r($output);
echo json_encode($output);
```

the output that i get is the following

```
{"Bulan":["Januari","Februari","Maret","April","Mei","Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember"],
"Total":["1","24","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
"Langsung":["0","19","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
"Delivery":["1","4","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
"Dropship":["0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]}.
```

full code used:

```
<?php

$data=json_decode('[
  {
    "Bulan": "Januari",
    "Total": "1",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "1",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Februari",
    "Total": "24",
    "Langsung": "19",
    "Delivery": "4",
    "Dropship": "1"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Maret",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "April",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Mei",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Juni",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Juli",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Agustus",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "September",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Oktober",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "November",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  },
  {
    "Bulan": "Desember",
    "Total": "0",
    "Langsung": "0",
    "Delivery": "0",
    "Dropship": "0"
  }
]',true);

$output=array();
foreach($data as $entry)
foreach($entry as $k=>$v)
{
if(!is_array($output[$k]))
$output[$k]=array();
$output[$k][]=$v;
}

print_r($output);
echo str_replace('],',"],\n",json_encode($output));
```

Comment: the result like this
{"":["Januari","1","0","1","0","Februari","24","19","4","1","Maret","0","0","0","0","April","0","0","0"
,"0","Mei","0","0","0","0","Juni","0","0","0","0","Juli","0","0","0","0","Agustus","0","0","0","0","September"
,"0","0","0","0","Oktober","0","0","0","0","November","0","0","0","0","Desember","0","0","0","0"]}